# Laravel database ordering issue when using joins and order by

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, mariadb

I have a project I am working on and I have a `Staff`, `Customer` & `Sale` Model.

As expected, `Staff` can have many `Sale`s which has one `Customer` - A `Customer` can also have many `Sale`s.

In a view I am working on, I want to display all the `Customer`s belonging to the `Staff` member, but display each `Customer` only once (DISTINCT, GROUP BY?) but in order of the most recent `Sale` (sale_date , DESC).

I have tried many different methods of showing this, but currently have this code:

```
Customer::join('sales', 'customers.id', '=', 'sales.customer_id')
->where('sales.staff_id',$id)
->orderBy('sales.sale_date', 'DESC')
->select('customers.*')
->get();
```

Which works for the most part except for the odd record where half way through August there will be a record from September. Here are some other ways I have tried:

```
$staff->sales()->orderBy('sale_date','DESC')->distinct('customer_id')->get();

Sale::select(DB::raw('s.*'))
->from(DB::raw('(SELECT * FROM sales WHERE staff_id = '.$id.' ORDER BY sale_date DESC) s'))
->groupBy('s.customer_id')
->orderBy('sale_date','DESC')
->get();
```

I don't particularly mind returning a collection of `Sale`s as I could modify my view to get the `Customer` for each `Sale`

Any help/advice would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Just also noticed, not even getting distinct customers anymore either :(

Comment: What happens if you replace ````Sale::select```` with ````DB::table('sales')````?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a modified `withCount()` to get the latest sale with a subquery:

```php
 Customer::withCount(['sales as sale_date' => function($query) {
        $query->select(DB::raw('max(sale_date)'));
    }])
    ->where('sales.staff_id', $id)
    ->orderByDesc('sale_date')
    ->get();
```

Comment: With this I get the following error: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'db.customers.business_name' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select `customers`.* from `customers` inner join `sales` on `customers`.`id` = `sales`.`customer_id` where `sales`.`staff_id` = 1 group by `customers`.`id` order by max(sales.sale_date) desc)

Comment: What's your MySQL version?

Comment: 10.3.9 - MariaDB

Comment: The suggested solution only works on MySQL. I updated my answer.

Comment: I was struggling to get anything working in the end, so settled for a long winded solution by getting all customers, removing duplicate key entries, then sorting the collection, then finally reversing the order. Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

According to the [joins documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#joins) the join feature use a DB rather than the model directly so try to replace `Sale::select` with `DB::table('sales')`.

Comment: Is there any way I can use this method while preserving Model instances? In the view I call model methods that are kind of crucial for the view. As it stands using this method, it is returning an array of stdClass objects.

Comment: In that case you need to use the ````Sales```` model and get the customer for each ````Sale````. Remember to eager load the customer model to reduce the number of queries.